# Does the popular open-source framework AFNetworking have a mechanism for logging requests/responses to console?

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I'd like to pump out the raw-ish HTTP requests/responses to the console to aid debugging.

I've looked at the various docs on GitHub and had a quick search through the code and couldn't find anything obvious, so I'm guessing the answer is no. But just wanted to check if I have missed anything obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AFURLConnectionOperation` sends notifications when operations start and end. You can easily log requests by listening for those notifications and logging the notification object:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:AFNetworkingOperationDidStartNotification
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:nil
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                NSLog(@"Operation Started: %@", [note object]);
                                              }];
```

Combine with [FormatterKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit)'s `TTTURLRequestFormatter` for best results!

Comment: Ah! I never thought of looking for NSNotification's. Thanks @mattt and thanks for the framework :-)